# induced homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ from the hypothetical existence of a homeomorphism between respective open subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ are not homeomorphic, and from this fact I want to show there is no homeomorphism between any pair of respective open subsets reasoning by contraction. Does it have a simple argument or should I use a specific theorem?

Comment: Hint: Any open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains an open ball, which is itself homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @DanielMroz but this only shows that $\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$ which in turn may not be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$, do I miss a point?

Comment: @selflearner: the open subset of $\Bbb R^m$ contains a ball homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^m$. You can look at restrictions to concoct a homeomorphism between $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: @Clayton restrictions to open balls in the domain lead to images that may not be open balls themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course

(1) If $n \ne m$, then there is no homeomorphism between an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an open subset of  $\mathbb{R}^m$

implies

(2) If $n \ne m$, then there is no homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and   $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I doubt that you can obtain (1) as an immediate corollary of (2). Both results are usually proved using the machinery of algebraic topology, but proving two results by the same method does not mean that there is simple deduction of one from the other.

A nice overview is contained in

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/invariance-of-domain/